# Finding the digits in text

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a file with the following content:

```
&ACCESS RVP1
&REL 3
&PARAM DISKPATH = KRC:\R1\Program\new
DEF SETUP_WELD()
;call LASER_EN();

$out[27]=false;  START=OFF
$out[26]=false;  STROBE=OFF
$out[25]=false;  SELECT 8=OFF
$out[24]=false;  SELECT 7 =OFF
$out[23]=false;  SELECT 6 =OFF
$out[22]=false;  SELECT 5 =OFF
$out[21]=false;  SELECT 4 =OFF
$out[20]=false;  SELECT 3 =OFF
$out[19]=false;  SELECT 2 =OFF
$out[18]=false;  SELECT 1 =OFF
$out[17]=false;  SELECT 0 =OFF
$out[28]=true;  ENABLE=ON

END
```

I need to find the value,that in the brackets [], and write it into array.
In result, I should get next result :

```
[ '27', '26','25','24','23','22','21','20','19','18','17','28']
```

I have to do it using Python. I'm pretty new to this, could you , please, , give me a hint what is the most proper way to do it?

My idea was something like this: I read the file into array,and then I was thinking about using the search in element of array:

```
def reading():
    with open ('Setup_Weld.src') as f:
        array1=[row.strip() for row in f]
```

But I don't know how to search in elements of array.

UPD: The answer was found. The working code is:

```
def reading():
    with open ('Setup_Weld.src') as f:
        stripped=[row.strip() for row in f]
        setup_weld_num = [re.search(r'\[(.*?)\]',i).group(1) for i in stripped if re.search(r'\[(.*?)\]',i)]
        print(setup_weld_num)
reading()
```

Comment: regex is the option with some google search. Show us the code you have tried ?

Comment: @Acapulka your change made the question significantly more complicated and invalidated existing answers. Consider reverting those changes, and starting a new question of you don't know how to deal with the extra lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try regex this is what you want,

```
import re
def reading():
    with open ('Setup_Weld.src') as f:
        stripped=[row.strip() for row in f]
        my_num_list = [re.search(br'\[(.*?)\]',i).group(1) for i in stripped if re.search(br'\[(.*?)\]',i)]
        print(my_num_list)
reading()
```

python3 output,

```
mohideen@botvfx-dev:~/Desktop$ python3 run.py 
[b'27', b'26', b'25', b'24', b'23', b'22', b'21', b'20', b'19', b'18', b'17', b'28']
mohideen@botvfx-dev:~/Desktop$
```

here is my output,

[image: here is my output,]

Comment: Tried your code, but it returns me error: TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object .     The file,that I'm opening, is not .txt, but I think this does not matter?

Comment: @Acapulka Add a `b` prefix to the pattern: `br'\[(.*?)\]'`

Comment: seems you re using python 3, so do 2 changes, as @DanD. said 'br' and my_num_list = [re.search(br'\[(.*?)\]',i).group(1) for i in f.readlines()]
print(my_num_list)

Comment: Tried, now it says " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' "

Comment: which means your txt doesnt match.. regex returns empty... i did from your above txt. did you save it in some name? like sam.txt?

Comment: I edited input in question. My fault, I didn't include whole content of file

Comment: @Acapulka i changed my code.. check my answer..  changed based on what you tried... Setup_Weld.src

Comment: Tried, still have "cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object"

Comment: ensure br in regex... or show your entire code with which version you're using

Comment: def reading():
    with open ('Setup_Weld.src') as f:
        stripped=[row.strip() for row in f]
        my_num_list = [re.search(br'\[(.*?)\]',i).group(1) for i in stripped if re.search(br'\[(.*?)\]',i)]
        print(my_num_list)
reading()      there is the code, and  python is 3.6

Comment: Finally it worked. I just removed 'b', thank you very much,sir!

Answer (score 0):

Use regex

```
import re
with open(file_name) as file_object:
    data=file_object.read().replace('\n', '')
    re.findall(r"\[(.*?)\]",data)
```

Comment: good answer. you can try .readlines() instead of .read() so you dont need to worry about '\n' replace

Comment: .readlines() will give data in list. By this i want to get data in a string. @MohideenibnMohammed

Comment: this could use some explanations

Answer (score 0):

Since the format is so simple, you can do this without regex, just using Python's string methods. Here's an adaptation of your start:

```
def reading():
    with open ('Setup_Weld.src') as f:
        array1=[row.strip() for row in f]
        return [line[5:].split(']')[0] for line in array1]
```

This removes the first four characters of each line, and then keeps the part before the closing bracket.

Output:

```
['27', '26', '25', '24', '23', '22', '21', '20', '19', '18', '17', '28']
```

Comment: seems like it worked, but something strange. I used this: def reading():
    with open ('Setup_Weld.src') as f:
        array1=[row.strip() for row in f]
        result=[line[5:].split(']')[0] for line in array1]
        print (result) and got next output:

Comment: ['SS RVP1', '3', 'M DISKPATH = KRC:\\R1\\Program\\new', 'ETUP_WELD()', ' LASER_EN();', '', '27', '26', '25', '24', '23', '22', '21', '20', '19', '18', '17', '28', '', '']

Comment: it will lookup all line.. regex will be a better solution... OP want to check will specific line

Comment: @Acapulka like I said in the comment on your question, your edit makes the question more complicated. This is a simple solution for the original version, but of course isn't intended for the more complex file, which was edited in after I posted this.